# image color become blue when using leftButtonIcon in NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I want add a left image in navigationbar,but it's color become blue 
my code like this:

```
return <NavigatorIOS 
            initialRoute = {{
                component:HomeScreen,
                title:'test',
                leftButtonIcon:require('../img/home_setting_icon.png'),
                translucent:false
            }}
        />
```

My image like this:
[image]
but the effect likes below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In iOS it depends on the bar tint color, set that to the desired one (e.g. purple)

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .green
```

For original image color:

```
someBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named:"myImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: I want origin color of image